# Use onclick to run a function

Tags: php, javascript, dictionary, onclick

I have a PHP page that has 3 JavaScript functions and uses image maps with 'onclick' to change the image and the map coordinates so that onclick runs the next function.

The code I have so far runs right the way through to the last image of the last function - which I understand. What I am trying to achieve is for the functions to call after the onclick one at a time in the new coordinates.

It is OK if there is a time limit by when each function will call - but before that time limit the onclick can run the next function:

```
    <img src=<?php echo 'image-start.jpg' ?> width="700" height="400" 
    usemap="#start" class="map" style="border-style:none; margin:0" id="imageX" />


    <map id="start" name="start">
    <area shape="poly"  id="A"  class=""  title="Click to Start"  onclick="myFunction_1()" 
        coords=<?php echo '"'; echo $coords_0; echo '"' ; ?>/>
    <area shape="poly"  id="B"  class=""  title="Click to Start"  onclick="myFunction_1()" 
        coords=<?php echo '"'; echo $coords_0; echo '"' ; ?>/>
    </map>



    <script>
    function myFunction_1() {
         document.getElementById("imageX").src=" <?php echo 'image_1.jpg' ?>  " ;

         document.getElementById("A").coords= <?php echo '"'; echo $coords_1_a; echo '"' ; ?> ;
         document.getElementById("A").onclick= myFunction_2() ;

         document.getElementById("B").coords= <?php echo '"'; echo $coords_1_b; echo '"' ; ?> ;
         document.getElementById("B").onclick= myFunction_2() ;
         }

    function myFunction_2() {
         document.getElementById("imageX").src=" <?php echo 'image_2.jpg' ?>  " ;

         document.getElementById("A").coords= <?php echo '"'; echo $coords_2_a; echo '"' ; ?> ;
         document.getElementById("A").onclick= myFunction_3() ;

         document.getElementById("B").coords= <?php echo '"'; echo $coords_2_b; echo '"' ; ?> ;
         document.getElementById("B").onclick= myFunction_3() ;
         }

    function myFunction_3() {
         document.getElementById("imageX").src=" <?php echo 'image_end.jpg' ?>  " ;
         }
    </script>
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, the code `<?php echo '"'; echo $coords_1_b; echo '"' ; ?>` can be simplified to `"<?=$coords_1_b?>"`. It would make things much easier to read.

Comment: I try to avoid server code mixed with client code at all costs. It becomes difficult to read, maintain, and scale. Moving the client logic out of the server template will make new features more simple to implement and easier to debug.

Comment: @DavidKiger using short tags is okay but it depends if the server has them on or they won't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cause one function to trigger another after a delay with `setTimeout()` -- for example, adding the following code to myFunction_1 will cause myFunction_2 to run in 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds)

```
setTimeout(myFunction_2, 5000)
```